# Creating a grid system that loops over each block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid

I'm attempting to create a simple grid system using python and have no idea where to start. Here's my code...

```
Columns = {
    "A": 'A',
    "B": 'B',
    "C": 'C',
    "D": 'D',
    "E": 'E',
    "F": 'F',
    "G": 'G',
    "H": 'H',
}

Rows = {
    "1": 1,
    "2": 2,
    "3": 3,
    "4": 4,
    "5": 5,
    "6": 6,
    "7": 7,
    "8": 8,
    "9": 9,
    "10": 10,
    "11": 11,
    "12": 12,
    "13": 13,
    "14": 14,
    "15": 15,
    "16": 16,
}
```

I would like the console to simply print out all combinations of these blocks.

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2
A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3
A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4
A5 B5 C5 D5 E5 F5 G5 H5
A6 B6 C6 D6 E6 F6 G6 H6
A7 B7 C7 D7 E7 F7 G7 H7
A8 B8 C8 D8 E8 F8 G8 H8
```

Answer (score 0):

seems a simple nested `for` loop (python3)

```
rows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for row in rows:
  for col in columns:
     print("%s%d" % (col, row), end=" ")
  print()
```

output

```
A1 B1 C1 D1
A2 B2 C2 D2
A3 B3 C3 D3
A4 B4 C4 D4
A5 B5 C5 D5
```

Comment: What does the %s and the %d represent?

Comment: Also is it possible to make each block (e.g, A1) its own object which can be true or false?

Comment: %s, %d are used for string formatting. In simple terms %s is placeholder for strings and %d for integers(decimals)

Comment: > Also is it possible to make each block (e.g, A1) its own object which can be true or false?

Off course, instead of(or in addition to) printing them out you can create a new map with these objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use the itertools to do a product (cross-join) of the lists. This code cross joins the keys of each dictionary.

```
import itertools

Columns = { "A": 'A', "B": 'B', "C": 'C', "D": 'D', "E": 'E', "F": 'F', "G": 'G', "H": 'H', }
Rows = { "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9, "10": 10, "11": 11, "12": 12, "13": 13, "14": 14, "15": 15, "16": 16, }

lst = [y+x for x,y in itertools.product(Rows,Columns)]  # cross join lists

print(" ".join(lst))
```

Output

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1 H1 A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2 A3 B3 C3 D3 E3 F3 G3 H3 A4 B4 C4 D4 E4 F4 G4 H4 A5 B5 C5 D5 E5 F5 G5 H5 A6 B6 C6 D6 E6 F6 G6 H6 A7 B7 C7 D7 E7 F7 G7 H7 A8 B8 C8 D8 E8 F8 G8 H8 A9 B9 C9 D9 E9 F9 G9 H9 A10 B10 C10 D10 E10 F10 G10 H10 A11 B11 C11 D11 E11 F11 G11 H11 A12 B12 C12 D12 E12 F12 G12 H12 A13 B13 C13 D13 E13 F13 G13 H13 A14 B14 C14 D14 E14 F14 G14 H14 A15 B15 C15 D15 E15 F15 G15 H15 A16 B16 C16 D16 E16 F16 G16 H16
```